# FTP + GZipStream = 'File is broken' when unzipped

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, gzip, gzipstream

I am trying to use a GZipStream to compress a document prior to uploading to an FTP server. If I save the compressed file stream to disk just prior to uploading, the copy on the local file system is correct. However, when I try to unzip the file on the FTP server I get a 'File is broken' error from 7zip. The resultant unzipped file is correct until the last few characters when a sequence of characters is repeated. I have tried many different configurations to no avail.

```
    public static void FTPPut_Compressed(string fileContents, string ftpPutPath)
    {
      using (var inStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(fileContents)))
      {
         inStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
         using (var outStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
         {
             using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(outStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
             {
                 inStream.CopyTo(zipStream);
                 outStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                 FTPPut(ftpPutPath, outStream.ToArray());
             }
         }
      }
    }

    private static void FTPPut(string ftpPutPath, byte[] fileContents)
    {
      FtpWebRequest request;

      request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(string.Format(@"ftp://{0}/{1}", Constants.FTPServerAddress, ftpPutPath))) as FtpWebRequest;
      request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
      request.UseBinary = true;
      request.UsePassive = true;
      request.KeepAlive = true;
      request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Constants.FTPUserName, Constants.FTPPassword);
      request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

      using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
      {
         requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
         requestStream.Close();
         requestStream.Flush();
      }
    }
```

Ex of corrupted output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
        <ArrayOfCreateRMACriteria xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <CreateRMACriteria>
                <RepairOrderId xsi:nil="true" />
                <RMANumber>11-11111</RMANumber>
                <CustomerId>1111</CustomerId>
            </CreateRMACriteria>
        </ArrayOfCreateRMACriteriafriafriafriafriafriafriafriafriafriafriafriafriafriafriafriafriafria
    <!-- missing '></xml>' -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not closing (and therefore flushing) the zip stream until *after* you've uploaded it. I suspect that may well be the problem. Move this line to *after* the `using` statement that creates/uses/closes the `GZipStream`:

```
FTPPut(ftpPutPath, outStream.ToArray());
```

... and get rid of the `Seek` call entirely. `ToArray` doesn't require it, and there's no suitable point in your code to call it. (If you call it before you flush and close the `GZipStream`, it will corrept the data; if you call it afterwards it'll fail as the `MemoryStream` is closed.) As an aside, when you *do* need to rewind a stream, I'd recommend using `stream.Position = 0;` as a simpler alternative.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Moving the outStream.ToArray() outside of the using block did the trick. You are also correct that the seek is not needed. That was a remnant from when I was passing streams to FTP instead of bytes. I have suggested a small edit, as its not whether the seek should be removed, but that it must be removed or it will throw a closed stream exception.

Comment: @TobinChee: Thanks - I've edited the answer accordingly.